# greedy regular expression or logic

Tags: python, regex

Consider the string `'X Y Z'` and the substitution

```
re.sub('Y|Y Z', '', 'X Y Z')
```

This returns

```
'X  Z'
```

When it could have returned `'X '` as well.  Obviously it took the first thing it matched, substituted, and afterwards the pattern for the other alternative no longer matched.

Is there a way to tell the substitution to prefer the longest substitution?

Comment: What would you like the result to be?

Comment: @ShammelLee 'X '

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44381861/3682217)

Comment: @ShammelLee upvoted already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Python `re` documentation - Regular Expression Syntax, `|` part](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax),

> `A|B`, where A and B can be arbitrary REs, creates a regular expression
>   that will match either A or B. An arbitrary number of REs can be
>   separated by the '|' in this way. This can be used inside groups (see
>   below) as well. As the target string is scanned, REs separated by '|'
>   are **tried from left to right. When one pattern completely matches,
>   that branch is accepted. This means that once A matches, B will not be
>   tested further, even if it would produce a longer overall match**. In
>   other words, the '|' operator is never greedy. To match a literal '|',
>   use \|, or enclose it inside a character class, as in [|].

Position the longest pattern before the shorter pattern:

```
>>> re.sub('Y Z|Y', '', 'X Y Z')
'X '
```

Answer (score 1):

## That would be…

```
re.sub('Y( Z)*','','X Y Z')
```